# update multiple rows of one column within one query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 100 of rows in one table and in that in one column is filepath.

It looks like below :

```
E:\test\file1.png
E:\test\file2.png
```

and so on..

Now I have renamed this folder to temp as per client requirements.

Now I need to do bulk update like below for this filepath column.

```
E:\temp\file1.png
E:\temp\file2.png
```

I am thinking to use Replace function but not sure is it feasible and also what will be easy syntax to use it.

Comment: Yes, REPLACE is typically used in situations like this.

Comment: What about your question is related to .Net and MVC? I see nothing in regards to either.

Comment: *"but not sure is it feasible"* Why do you think is isn't feasible for this? When you tried to use it, why didn't it work as you expected?

Comment: you can first run: select path, replace(path, '\test\', '\temp\') from your table to see how it changes the values, and then do the replace if you're satisfied. The only problem with replace is that it's easy to replace unintended parts, but otherwise it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use logic of this query as below:

1. add your table name without table
2. add your column name without fiepath

```sql
update table set filepath =replace(filepath,'test','temp')
```

Comment: This is potentially harmful. If there are any other matches for the string 'test' they will also be replaced. It would be better to use something more explicit, such as `REPLACE(filepath,'\test\','\temp\')`